# Using HttpContext.Current.Item to cache Data Access Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have dashboard pages with data grids and charts that make nearly 10 data access calls per request. The dashboards orbit around a SQL table named Purchases. Due to one reason or another, this Purchases table has grown in complexity and eventually 5 other tables and 1 View are needed to be joined together to get the right data.

I took a gamble and created a nested SQL view out of them.

Long story short, I now must buffer the Purchase View data in a temp table of fixed name at beginning of every data call to avoid query time-out.

I have an idea that I think may work, but I don't want to find out that it doesn't after moving to Production. I wish someone with experience can help me validate it.

It's actually pretty simple:

- To begin I write a stored procedure that would query the view, and dump the data into a temp table IF it doesn't exist in current session (maybe index it it...)
- At the beginning of every data call in C# that requires Purchase data, call the SP
- Implement my Data Access class such that it implements IDisposible interface. At Dispose() implementation, call myConnection.Dispose() to close the connection and return it to the pool
- At Application_BeginRequest in Global.asax, instantiate DataAccess class and put the instance in HttpContext.Current.Items
- Whenever DataAccess object is required from any page or their supporting classes, refer to the instance in HttpContext.Current.Items
- At Application_EndRequest in Global.asax, call DataAccess object's Dispose() method to free up the temp table, among other things

Will this work? Any gotcha's I need to be aware of?

Comment: Terrible idea, database connections shouldn't in general be kept open. Why not cache the data in the server cache, and leave the database out of it? Although are you really sure you can't optimise the SQL? Doesn't sound right it should take that long.

Comment: It's kept open only for the duration of the current request, which is measured in seconds anyway. The purchase data needed to be joined with grid and chart data, so it doesn't make sense to cache at application level. I am interfacing with a content management system, so I don't get full control of the schemas for de-normalization.

Comment: You says specifically "put the DataAccess" object in the cache? If thats not the connection what is it? And it certainly does make sense to cache it in the application, that where one should do that sort of thing.

Comment: So to clarify, you're just caching the data for a single request? If so definitely cache it in the application and avoid any need to call the database again.

Comment: Life time of HttpContext.Current.Items collection only lasts for the duration of the request. That's why I call Dispose at Application_EndRequest to free up the connection. LIke i said all the charts and grids rely on Purchase data, i would rather keep it at DB level to allow easy joining

Comment: Well whether it will work will depend on how many requests your server gets at the same time. Keeping a connection open for the duration of a request is still quite a long time when measured in server time. On the plus side you don't need to drop the temp table as closing the connection will do that automatically. You can't create the temp table within the SP though, because it gets dropped at the end of it. Unless you use a global temp table.

Comment: I would not recommend relying on IDisposables inside HttpContext.Current.Items getting freed up inside Application_EndRequest. You'll likely leak connections, etc., if any HTTP Request Timeouts or any other internal server errors occur.

Comment: 100+ seconds that less than successful request can easily take is eternity for most practical purposes... You are basically building system that will quickly degrade to complete shutdown in case of minor failures... which is generally opposite of what most system try to achieve - slightly degraded performance in case of even major failures.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Is there a better, more reliable place for it, such as Page_LoadComplete, or Page_Unload? Or is this generally a poor design pattern and should not be used?

Comment: If you're designing for scalability then you should contain all of your queries within `using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))` blocks so that connections are returned to the Connection Pool as soon as possible. Any other pattern, e.g.: trying to persist connections and pass them around, will result in your Connection Pool running out of connections as the number of users increases.